# Palabras superpuestas en encabezamientos de documento LaTeX

Tags: latex, headers

Redactando un documento en Overleaf me sucede lo siguiente en algunos encabezamientos de página debido a que los títulos son largos:

[image: Imagen que muestra la superposición de palabras en un encabezamiento del documento]

He estado buscando formas de reducir el tamaño del texto o incrementar el espacio entre palabras sin afectar al resto del contenido, limitándose únicamente a los encabezamientos, pero no he localizado nada que me sirva.

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma de hacerlo evitando la superposición sin necesidad de reducir la extensión de los títulos.

Por si es necesario dejo los paquetes que utilizo en mi documento:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{longtable}

 

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,head=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[usenames]{color}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage[official]{eurosym}

\usepackage{float} % para usar [H]

\usepackage{graphicx} % LaTeX

\usepackage{framed}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

\usepackage{xurl}

\parindent 0em

\parskip 2ex

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

 

%Cabecera

 

\chead{\tiny{}}

 

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \rightmark}

\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape \leftmark}

 

 

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

 

 

\lfoot{Crossroads 2.0}\cfoot{}\rfoot{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.6pt}

 

\author{ \textbf{"Título del documento"

 } \\Autor

 

\date{\today}}

\date{}
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

He continuado investigando y por fin he logrado dar con una solución. La dejo aquí por si alguien la necesita:

A través de fancyhead:

```
\fontsize{10}{11}\selectfont
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\changefont \slshape \rightmark
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\changefont \slshape \leftmark}
```

El resultado obtenido ha sido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el sitio web donde he encontrado la información es:

https://texblog.org/2012/10/09/changing-the-font-size-in-fancyhdr/